# Display all items in a json array

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to work with json and I almost have what I need. I am getting the correct info to display but I am having to pass each item of an array into a variable and then print the variable. I would like to display all of the items in each array. The json data I am working with is from an invoicing app ([www.curdbee.com](http://www.curdbee.com)) and I am trying to show each invoice for a client. The data that I want to show is each line item, the line item price, and the total amount. Here is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {


    $.getJSON('https://nspirelab.curdbee.com/invoices.json?api_token=__token__', function(data){
        $.each(data, function(index, item){
            var total = item.invoice.total_billed;
            var lineItemName1 = item.invoice.line_items[0].name_and_description;
            var lineItemName2 = item.invoice.line_items[1].name_and_description;
            var lineItemPrice1 = item.invoice.line_items[0].price; 
            var lineItemPrice2 = item.invoice.line_items[1].price; 

            $('#results').append('<div class="lineItem"><ul><li>' + lineItemName1 + lineItemPrice1 + '</li><li>' + lineItemName2 + lineItemPrice2 + '</li><li>' + total + '</li></ul></div>');
        });

    });

});
```

Comment: Even then, it could still show up in data dumps, nothing here is ever really deleted. I'd strongly advise getting a new token, just to be safe :)

Comment: Yikes thanks! I got a new token just to be safe.

Comment: Is the token really that important? One could go on to the site and look at the source code :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A nested loop (or, in jQuery, a nested `$.each()`) will do the job:

```
$.getJSON('https://nspirelab.curdbee.com/invoices.json?api_token=&client=104929', function(data){
   $.each(data, function(index, item){
      // create an empty ul (initially disconnected from the DOM)
      var $ul = $("<ul/>");

      // iterate over the line items
      $.each(item.invoice.line_items, function(i, lineItem) {
         // create an li element with the line details and append
         // it to the ul
         $ul.append( $("<li/>").html(lineItem.name_and_description + lineItem.price) );
      });

     // add the totals to the end of the ul
     $ul.append( $("<li/>").html(item.invoice.total_billed) );

     // create a new div, append the ul to it, and append the div to results
     $('#results').append( $('<div class="lineItem"/>').append($ul) );
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a ridiculous number of libraries out there to make things like this easier.  Do a search for "javascript templates" to see what you've been missing and to learn about the various libraries you can choose between for this.

Comment: Ok great thanks. I am new to js/jquery/json so I will definitely take a look at javascript templates.

Comment: cool.  dont feel overwhelmed as you dig into this... it's really quite absurd how many people have thought to themselves "hey you know what the wold needs?  another js templating library.  i'll build that today".  for typical usage, they area all pretty much the same so don't stress over picking the right one

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question properly, I think what you are searching for is some sort of iterating mechanisms, try [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/).